# How to override my custom button's event without specify page variables

Tags: c#

I created a `CustomButton`, inherited from `Button` class. Then I created some event, like `GotFocus`, `LostFocus`, etc.

```
public sealed class CustomButton : Button
{
    public CustomButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomButton);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        this.GotFocus += CustomButton_GotFocus;
        this.LostFocus += CustomButton_LostFocus;

        base.OnApplyTemplate();

    }

    private void CustomButton_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some common behavior code
    }

    private void CustomButton_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some common behavior code
    }
}
```

Then I used this `CustomButton` in some pages. But in some specified pages, I don't want the `CustomButton` excute the `GotFocus`, `LostFocus` event.

So how to override these event in the specified pages?

I tried add `GotFocus`, `LostFocus` event in the specified pages, but it will finally run the common code behavior in `CustomButton`.

Comment: you can create a property `UseBaseClass` and do something like `if (UseBaseClass) 
      base.LostFocus(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the requirement, you could make a `DependencyProperty` to control the `GotFocus` or `LostFocus` event could be excuted or not.

For example:

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public CustomButton()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Button);
        Current = this;
    }
    private static CustomButton Current;
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {     
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }


    public bool EnableDetected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(EnableDetectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnableDetectedProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EnableDetected.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableDetectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EnableDetected", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomButton), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((bool)e.NewValue  == true)
        {
            Current.GettingFocus += Current_GettingFocus;
        }
        else
        {
            Current.GettingFocus -= Current_GettingFocus;
        }
    }

    private static void Current_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
    {

    } 
}
```

**Usage**

```
 <local:CustomButton Content="Btn"  EnableDetected="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can "take off" the events out of the CustomButton by iterating the page controls:

```
foreach(var cb in this.Controls.OfType<CustomButton>())
{
    cb.GotFocus -= CustomButton.GotFocus;
    cb.LostFocus -= CustomButton.LostFocus;
}
```

I believe this should work.

Comment: You mean I put the code in my specified pages? The compiler can't recognize `CustomButton_GotFocus`.

Comment: Yes, and my bad, it should be a dot